# Convergence of sequences, measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I need help with this exercise:

We say that the sequence ${f:n:n\geq 1}$ converges in $L^1$ if there is a measurable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N\geq 1 \forall n\geq N: \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|d\lambda<\epsilon$$

What are similar definitions for pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of the sequence ${f_n:n\geq 1}$?

Considerating that $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are with the Euclidean topology and the  Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

b) Check the following sequences of functions for convergence in all three modes:

a) $f_n(x)=x^n, x\in [0,1]$
b)$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}sin(2\pi n x), x \in [0,1]$
c)$f_n(x)=1_{A_n}$ where $A_n=[k2^{-m},(k+1)2^{-m}]$ with $m=[log_2(n)]=sup[i \geq 0:2î\leq n]$ and $k=n-2^m$

Well, the first part I have gotten this:

For uniform convergence:
The sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to f if for every $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ and for every $x\in X$ $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq \epsilon$.

On the other hand, i have the definition of pointwise convergence:

We say that $f_n$ conerges to $f$ pointwise if, for every $x\in X$ $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$. In other words, there exists $N$ (that depends of $\epsilon$ and $x$), such that:
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$.

Now, here my first question is if in the previous definition there is a influence of the Lebesgue measure?, I know that the Euclidean topology is given by the $| |$.

Also, I don´t understand how to use the definitions to analyze sequences for instance:  $x^n$, first what is $f(x)$, what is the integral $\int_\mathbb{R}$ how to integrate this function if it depends of $\lambda$?, In every definition what is the value of $\epsilon$ I am so confused with this definitions and the usage of them.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  The math formatting is nicely done, but you may find Readers are reluctant to respond to a simple quotation of an exercise, as if you were reassigning responsibility to them.  Multiple part exercises are particularly seen as reflecting a lack of effort when no evidence is shown that parts have been sorted through.  Surely not all parts of the above are equally difficult. As the Original Poster you have the responsibility of narrowing down the "learning opportunity" to a point you have difficulty with, so that responses can effectively help with that.

Comment: (Replying to a now deleted comment by OP): Then perhaps your difficulty was with applying one of the three definitions to one of the three specified sequences?  Readers are unlikely to want to give nine detailed explanations when actually the point that interests you is quite narrow.

Comment: I have found the definitions on internet, but I dont know how to use in evey function, what is the value of epsilon? what is N?  I am not familiar with this kind of definitions.

Comment: Then your Question has to be first about understanding the definitions before you ask about various applications.  I would look at previous Questions about (say) pointwise convergence, which may be the simplest of the three concepts (it pertains only to convergence of the sequences evaluated at all the individual points $x=x_0$).